# Different locales for front-end and back-end in Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I need to set 2 separate static locales so front-end is always in English and back-end in Russian.
Adding this to `/config/initializers/spree.rb` or `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` has no effect:

```
Spree::Frontend::Config[:locale] = :en
Spree::Backend::Config[:locale] = :ru
```

There was a PR where Ryan Bigg addressed this issue when splitting core in front-end and back-end https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/78b032dcfc02d362af780d6154ff300fbc0e95b0

I just couldn't find where to put the code or maybe my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
# app/controllers/spree/admin/base_controller_decorator.rb
Spree::Admin::BaseController.class_eval do
  before_filter do
    I18n.locale = :ru
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me to get the Backend in a custom locale (different than the Frontend locale) was adding this to `app/config/initializers/spree.rb`:

```
Spree::Backend::Config[:locale] = :ru
```

This is on Spree 4.1 (Rails 6.0.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

In Spree 4.2 Multi-Currency is OOTB and you can set different multiple locales for Storefront and Admin Panel - https://guides.spreecommerce.org/release_notes/4_2_0.html